# How to consume List from another class

Tags: c#, oop

Whenever I give new when instantiating a class or list, will it be recreated? I'm having trouble consuming a list that I fed into another class.
I'll give an example of my question to make it clearer:

I have the Customers class:

```
public class Customers
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; } 
}
```

and I have another class called:

```
public class CustomerList
{
    public List<Customers> dataCustomers;
}
```

these two are inside the same file or better same namespace.

Now I will feed this list through another Form1, so first I will instantiate it in this new form1:

```
CustomerList listCustomers = new CustomerList();
```

Now I'm going to feed the data into the class:

```
Customers customer = new Customers()
{
     id = 1,
     name = "Matthew"
}
```

and finally I will add the records inside the list:

```
listCustomer.dataCustomers.Add(customer);
```

Now I want to consume this list from another form/class, but I don't know how to do it. I tried instantiating it again in this new class. but it always returns saying that dataCustomers was null, saying that the object is not being referenced. so well I couldn't understand this concept well, how to consume a list that I fed into another form/class.

In this form that I want to consume, I did it like this, I instantiated it:

```
CustomerList objCliente = new CustomerList();
```

and to test, I tried to play inside a message box, just to see the result.

```
MessageBox.Show(objCliente.dataCustomers.ToString());
```

Comment: What is a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your property to be static, so that it can be accessed anywhere.

```
public class CustomerList
{
    static public List<Customers> dataCustomers;
}
```

The way to add new customer now become like this :

```
CustomerList.dataCustomers.Add(customer);
```

and to access it also same. You can access it using this way :

```
CustomerList.dataCustomers
```